# oracle sql expdp -> database pump while users a writing to the databse

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use Oracle 11GR2 on openSuse and we do a Oracle Data Pump with the command `expdp` of all the schemas.

My Question is: what happens if a user updates the database trough the application while the `expdp` command runs on the server.

Am I guaranteed to get a consistent state?

Answer (score 0):

No your are not unless you specify: flashback_time or flashback_scn

here is the link to the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL850